# How to set the public property of a class to an instance of another class?

Tags: vb.net, class, properties, variable-assignment

I'm trying to access a WCF WebService using VB.Net. So far I've succesfully set up the connected service via WSDL and exposed the methods and classes from the service.

The error I'm stuck at is

```
BC30311 - The value of type 'CatalogItemUpdateCommand' cannot be converted to 'CatalogItemUpdateCommand()'.
```

I have a class CatalogUpdateRequest, with a public property Items() set to another class, named CatalogItemUpdateCommand.

The code for CatalogItemUpdateCommand class:

```
Partial Public Class CatalogItemUpdateCommand
        Inherits Object
        Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
             Private CatalogItemCodeField As String
             Private PriceField As Decimal

        Public Property CatalogItemCode() As String
            Get
                Return Me.CatalogItemCodeField
            End Get
            Set
                If (Object.ReferenceEquals(Me.CatalogItemCodeField, value) <> true) Then
                    Me.CatalogItemCodeField = value
                    Me.RaisePropertyChanged("CatalogItemCode")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

    Public Property Price() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.PriceField
        End Get
        Set
            If (Me.PriceField.Equals(value) <> true) Then
                Me.PriceField = value
                Me.RaisePropertyChanged("Price")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

The code for CatalogUpdateRequest class:

```
Partial Public Class CatalogUpdateRequest
        Inherits Object
        Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
Private ItemsField() As SEAP.CatalogItemUpdateCommand
Public Property Items() As SEAP.CatalogItemUpdateCommand()
            Get
                Return Me.ItemsField
            End Get
            Set
                If (Object.ReferenceEquals(Me.ItemsField, Value) <> True) Then
                    Me.ItemsField = Value
                    Me.RaisePropertyChanged("Items")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
```

The code to call the service:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim items_to_update As CatalogItemUpdateCommand = New CatalogItemUpdateCommand
        Dim items_update_request As CatalogUpdateRequest = New CatalogUpdateRequest With {.Items = items_to_update}
        Dim final_update_request As Catalog_UpdateItemsRequest = New Catalog_UpdateItemsRequest(request:=items_update_request)
        Try
            'Assign values to parameters
            items_to_update.CatalogItemCode = "00011587"
            items_to_update.InStock = "true"
            items_to_update.Price = 7.53
            items_to_update.DoUpdatePrice = "true"
            items_to_update.DoUpdateStock = "true"
            items_to_update.DoPublish = "true"
            items_to_update.DoProcessPublish = "true"
            'Call the Catalog_UpdateItems method from the interface
            seapclient.Catalog_UpdateItems(final_update_request)
        Catch wex As WebException
        End Try
    End Sub
```

This line generates the error mentioned above:

```
Dim items_update_request As CatalogUpdateRequest = New CatalogUpdateRequest With {.Items = items_to_update}
```

I get the same error if I state:

```
items_update_request.Items = items_to_update
```

inside the Try... End Try block

```
BC30311 - The value of type 'CatalogItemUpdateCommand' cannot be converted to 'CatalogItemUpdateCommand()'.
```

It seems to be a declaration issue. Any suggestions?

Later edit: Thanks, guys, declaring ar array() seemed to have done the trick!

New code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim items_to_update(1) As CatalogItemUpdateCommand
        Dim items_update_request As CatalogUpdateRequest = New CatalogUpdateRequest() ' With {.Items = items_to_update}
        Dim final_update_request As Catalog_UpdateItemsRequest = New Catalog_UpdateItemsRequest()
        Dim update_response As Catalog_UpdateItemsResponse
        Dim update_result As CatalogImportResponse
        Try
            'Assign values to parameters


            items_to_update(0) = New CatalogItemUpdateCommand With {.CatalogItemCode = "00011587", .Price = 7.54, .DoUpdatePrice = "true", .InStock = "true", .DoPublish = "true", .DoProcessPublish = "true"}
            '
            items_update_request.Items = items_to_update
            final_update_request.request = items_update_request
            'Call the Catalog_UpdateItems method from the interface
            update_response = seapclient.Catalog_UpdateItems(final_update_request)
            txtResponse.Text = "Status: " & update_response.Catalog_UpdateItemsResult.Status.ToString & "Updated: " & update_response.Catalog_UpdateItemsResult.Updated.ToString() & "Failed: " & update_response.Catalog_UpdateItemsResult.Failed.ToString()
        Catch wex As WebException
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Moving on to assigning values to array from SQL Database, keep in touch...

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. You're trying to use a single `CatalogItemUpdateCommand` where an array of that type is expected.

Comment: Why do you have an empty `Catch` block?

Comment: @Jonathan Willcock Unfortunately, `Price() as Decimal` doesn't define an array of decimals, but a decimal type. `Price() as Decimal()` or `Price as Decimal()` would (as in `Public Property Items() As SEAP.CatalogItemUpdateCommand()`). Those parentheses are not required and can be removed from the property name definition (i.e., `Property Price as Decimal`)